# Conditions in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript regex to validate the URL filed as

```
var regex = /^(?:https?|ftp)\:\/\/....
```

If I want to add "file://" protocol support to it with 2 (or) 3 slashes following, it became

```
var regex = /^(?:https?|ftp|file)\:\/\/(\/?)....
```

Problem with this is, it is validating "http:///" also to true. 
Is there any way to accept the third slash only if the "file" protocol is present without writing a separate regex?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to separate the `file:` test from the rest of the tests:

```
/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^/]+|file:\/\/\/?)...
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to put it into the alternation:

```
var regex = /^(?:https?:|ftp:|file:\/?)\/\/....
```

in that case you would need to add also the colon to every alternation.